# How to "hide" utility functions in cpp -- code design question?

Tags: c++

I have a utility package of functions that really don't fit into a class, as they effectively are a set of functionality across two classes (and due to MISRA, can't put them in a class that inherits both).

The code structure is as follows, in the body (cpp) file:

```
namespace myName {
   void a(args)
   {
   // some stuff here
   }

   void b(args)
   {
   // some stuff here 
   }

   void c(args)
   {
      a(args);
      b(args);
   }
}
```

Now, I want to call `c` elsewhere in other classes. However, `a` and `b` should not be called anywhere else, yet the compile says I need to put all three in the header file. If I were using classes, `a` and `b` would therefore go into the private area, or be declared static. If I were using Ada, they'd be local functions within `c`.

This is not an opinion question, the answer just needs to fulfil the following (to iterate): 
How can I not expose `a` and `b` in this utility package without the use of a class?

(The answer might actually be "use a class and restructure your code properly.)

Comment: The compiler would not demand they be put in a header, only the static analyzer may. Does it still do it when you make them `static`?

Comment: "the compile says I need to put all three in the header file": can you clarify this? I think you have a misunderstanding here. The compiler wants to see at least a declaration (if not the whole definition) before the function is used, but there's no need to have it in a .h file. You can put those forward declarations at the top of your .cc file, thus satisfying the compiler without exposing them to users.

Comment: If `void c` is implemented in source instead of header, the header does not need to know about a and b

Comment: I've added a comment to clarify. The compiler error was about "no previous declaration of `a` and `b`.

Comment: The header file should only contain a *declaration* of `c`.

Comment: That's what "private" is for. But the class "declaration" must have all functions.
Another idea is to make a class that only has "c" and derive a class that has "a" and "b" from that and only expose the first class.

Comment: How can I not expose a and b in this utility package without the use of a class? - By using a class. :-P

Answer (score 1):

You can have the header expose the interface which you want exposed to the user, and have the helpers encapsulated within another cpp file.

It would look something like this:

```cpp
/**
 * @file my_name.hpp
 */
#pragma once

namespace my_name {
   extern void c(void *args);
}
```

```cpp
/**
 * @file my_name.cpp
 */

namespace my_name 
{
    static inline void a(void *args)
    {
        // some stuff here
    }

    static inline void b(void *args)
    {
        // some stuff here 
    }

    void c(void *args)
    {
        a(args);
        b(args);
    }
}
```

```cpp
/**
 * @file main.cpp
 */

#include "my_name.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // | main.cpp:10:14: error: 'a' is not a member of 'my_name'
    // my_name::a(nullptr);
    // | main.cpp:12:14: error: 'b' is not a member of 'my_name'
    // my_name::b(nullptr);    
    my_name::c(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

If the user tries to be clever and put this code into `main.cpp`:

```cpp
namespace my_name {
   extern void a(void *args);
   extern void b(void *args);
}
```

There would be a compile-time linking error when trying to call them, as they are defined static(file local).

sidenotes:

1. You can omit the inline if you have reasons you don't want to hint inlining, I put it there as an annotation to be clear to the readers that I expect the function to be inlined, it will almost certaintly be inlined in this case by any compiler capable of doing so(as it is file-local and has no pointers to them, etc) even without the keyword. The inline keyword does not guarantee it will be inlined, and will be ignored if the compiler finds reasons not to inline it.
2. extern on functions does nothing(as far as I am aware), I just wanted to make an explicit contrast to the static in the definition of a and b.
3. as far as I have tested, this solution has the cost of `c` being not inlineable, whereas a class or a header internal "trust-the-user-not-to-try-using it" approach would allow these functions to be inlined, eg it would still get called even if it does absolutely nothing, even with the `-O3` flag.

Comment: `extern` is unnecessary on functions, I believe.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I modified my sidenote to explain my reasoning for adding it, let me know if there is any harm introduced by making it explicit.

Comment: `inline` doesn't actually hint at inlining, not in how C++ is specified anyway. It only serves a purpose for the ODR when the functions have external linkage. With or without it, a compiler will reason about inlining entirely on its own. My personal experience is that compilers care much more about the `static` for such internal utility functions. That allows them to inline aggressively, not just inling the code of the function, but also not emitting a symbol for it at all (if the address is not taken).

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica I am aware that static pretty much guarantees it will be inlined unless very specific things are done to make it not, and if these things are done, inline would probably not do anything. It is more of an annotation that I expect it to be inlined rather than anything to do with the compiler, although I want to believe it helps some compiler be sure what my intent of these functions was - to be inlined.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Compiler behavior and how idiomatic code looks evolve together. So I'd genuinely question the use here, if I was reviewing it. The reasoning around it is entirely moot.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica *"inline doesn't actually hint at inlining"* That's something we tell each other until we forget it's a lie. :P I remember checking the sources of GCC and Clang (or reading a post by somebody who did), and it does affect the inlining decision.

Answer (score 0):

Header files are "interfaces" (not in an OOP sense) of translation units.
What the consumer of an API **needs** to see/know goes into a header.
What the consumer does not need to see/know goes into a cpp.

`File A.h`

```cpp
namespace foo {

    void a();
}
```

`File A.cpp`

```
namespace foo {
    void a() {
    // implementation
    }
}
```

`File B.cpp`

```
#include "A.h" // Make "foo::a()" visible to B

namespace bar {

    void b() {
        foo::a();
    }
}
```

It's perfectly valid (and also encouraged) to hide implementation details into cpp files without a header counter part.

Comment: Hmmm. What use is `bar::b` if it's only in a `cpp` file where it's never used?